# Is there a way to track a user's review history?

Tags: support, review, users

Is there a way to see an individual's review history?  I don't think there is.

I've checked the *tools* page on the review menu, a privilege afforded to users with 10K, and didn't find what I was looking for.

I can see the history of *everyone* who voted to close, reopen, etc. on EL&U but I cannot trace a user's personal track history.

> The full history of reviews by **all users** in any /[review queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues)

I mean, technically, I could track a single user's record if I manually waded through possibly hundreds of pages but life is too short. Moreover, a user who has reviewed at least 1,000 posts is awarded the [Steward](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/badges/185/steward) gold badge, but that doesn't tell me if they have cast to close 1,000 or 899 times a question, I just know they have reviewed that number of posts.

Why? I like to be sure before asking someone why they *always* vote to close and *never* cast a vote to [reopen](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions) a question. I could also be very well be mistaken in thinking their voting is heavily biased.  It would also be nice to know exactly how many review tasks they have performed, especially if it runs in the hundreds.

It's a question of getting my facts straight and knowing the full story. I do not believe this is a question of anonymity because *any* user with at least 10K can see the history of voting on every single post that has been reviewed on EL&U.

### Addendum

While rummaging I found a very easy way of finding this type of statistic, SE does actually provide this tool but maybe not everyone knows about this. So... maybe this post will prove useful.

**P.S** Before posting my request and then finding the solution, I searched the MSE archives using the following terms `review queue stats user history` and got [16 results](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=review%20queue%20stats%20user%20history%20) None of which helped me, until I had that eureka moment.

Comment: I'm curious to know why this post is unclear, not useful, or does not show any research.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### Yes.

This is public, and located in the [User Profile](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current) → [Activity](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=topactivity) → [all actions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity) → [reviews](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/current?tab=activity&sort=reviews), e.g. yours here:

> [image: Mari-Lou reviews in MSE]

Note it lists only reviews made on posts which are not deleted, i.e. that any visitor can see. When a post is deleted, the review item is removed from that page.

Comment: Does it show Low Quality Post review history?

Comment: @scaaahu it should, yes. If you have a counter example please share and I'll give another look.

Comment: @scaaahu I almost don't use the review system here. I act upon seeing the posts. (Which for new posts is usually matter of seconds/minutes after being posted)

Comment: This page **doesn't show all reviews** (for example, I think it doesn't show reviews of posts which were later deleted). I've often noticed it to be severely incomplete. For example, [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/users/31394/rand-althor?tab=activity&sort=reviews) you can't see any of the LQPs where I've clicked Delete ([one](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/140871), [two](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/140785), [three](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/140630) in the last few days).

Comment: @Randal'Thor good point, edited to reflect that. Anyway, that's the best we can get, and it's consistent with other places all around. (no lists with deleted posts.)

Comment: However, there is one snag. I mean, this is the answer and the kind of data I was looking for but the UP doesn't record the instances when I have voted to close a question for being off-topic outside the review queue. How come?

Comment: @Mari-LouA Because this is a list of *reviews*. Anything you do outside the review queue isn't a review.

Comment: @Randal'Thor OK, what I mean is why are those instances not recorded? I have voted to close perhaps hundreds of off-topic posts on EL&U on the main page.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Because they're not reviews. Also, they're private up to the point where the question is actually closed (if it is).

Comment: @Mari-LouA You can view a list of your own close votes in the "votes" tab in your profile.